# Parameterized oracle command c#

Tags: c#, parameterized, oraclecommand

I have a problem using parameterized oracle command. The command seem to recognise all the string parameters (:Id,:CreateUser) but not the character parameter(:Active).

```
string qry = @"Insert into GROUP_LOGIN 
               (
                GROUP_ID,
                CREATED_ON,
                ACTIVE_FLAG,
                CREATED_USER
               ) 
               values
               (
                :Id, 
                SYSDATE,
                :Active,
                :CreateUser
               )";

OracleCommand cmd = dal.GetOracleCommand();

if (cmd != null)
{
  cmd.CommandText = qry;
  OracleParameter op=   new OracleParameter("Active",OracleDbType.Char);
  op.Value = active;
  //cmd.Parameters.Add(op);

  OracleParameter[] myParams = new OracleParameter[]  
      { 
        new OracleParameter("Id", this.GrpID), 
        new OracleParameter("Description", this.Description),
        new OracleParameter("CreateUser", this.Create_User),
        new OracleParameter("Remarks", this.Remarks),
        op
      };

  for (int i = 0; i < myParams.Length; i++) 
  {
      cmd.Parameters.Add(myParams[i]);
  }

  //...
}
```

I have tried different ways of doing this but everytime I use these two types of parameters the char parameter does not get recognised. When the character parameters is only considered, it works correctly but else it gives error

```
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("User"."GROUP_LOGIN"."ACTIVE_FLAG")
```

Comment: Have you tried casting `active` to a string and passing it through?

Answer (score 0):

You set the (apparently) null value with `op.Value = active;`, have you made sure that `active` truly has some value? Based on this code, it could be null and the error message would be valid in that case.

Comment: Yes active have value ('I') and the parameter 'op' value is also not null ('I'). In fact the command shows all 3 parameters with their respective values